# What is the time complexity of Kafka consume

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

What is the time complexity of Kafka consumer in big O. Is the offset metadata that Kafka maintains allows for O(1) complexity for reads

Answer (score 0):

Short answer- no, the time depends on the number and size of evets consumed, networking and poll configuration.
You can say that regular case should be pretty fast, involving only memory access and minor network overhead.

If you know the offset you are seeking for, or just want to get events from the last commited offset, you know the offset number immedietly, but the consume process also invloving get the data from the broker/s and send it to the consumer.

Kafka stores recent events in memory and later spills them to disk in chunks.
Consuming from memory is relatively fast, but yet not percise to define as "O(1)".
So assuming you are reading from the latest offset and waiting for new events, if configured correctly the broker/s holding the partitions of the topic should have all the desired events available in memory and total time of the polling, i.e consuming is the time taken to the broker/s accessing memory and sending the new events over the network.

Moreover, if small number of events is produced to the topic, the consumer poll may finish only when poll timeout is triggered, in this case you probably encountered situation where you waited idle without doing nothing for some of the time.
Also if Kafka Coordonator rebalance just happend (not likely) it may cause further delay.